# AWS APPFLOW | Trigger / Activate AWS Appflow flow from other than console

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, saas

How can i activate AWS APPFLOW flow by not using AWS Console but by using Rest API or Python or AWS CLI?
I am not able to find any support from AWS Documentation or any blogs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use StartFlow API call. Please check the description in the documentation:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/1.0/APIReference/API_StartFlow.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/appflow/start-flow.html
   The first documentation has the link to SDK implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you use CloudFormation, you can create a Lambda-backed custom resource, which is going to be triggered during CloudFormation create/update/delete events. The Lambda function will be called with those events, and you can call AppFlow SDK to activate/deactivate the flows.

Answer (score 0):

AWS recently released APIs for Appflow and also support with Cloudformation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/1.0/APIReference/Welcome.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-appflow-flow.html